# mvn command not working even with maven installed in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot application in STS.
The application has maven dependencies and pom.xml working fine.
So maven is installed and running fine on it.

Now I want to run mvn commands.

But if I go to STS terminal or windows command prompt and run an mvn command (ie. mvn -version) I get the following error message:
mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command

Doing some research I found that maven needs to be installed such as below:
\program files\apache-maven-x-x-x

and then M2_HOME environment variable needs to be created.

Checking on my system I couldn't find that apache-maven-x-x-x folder.
At least not under \program files.

So I'm wondering if downloading maven and installing on that folder won't conflict with the maven that I already have installed on STS.
Or should I fix this in some other way since I already have maven on STS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easiest way to install it
once you have MAVEN_HOME in your env you can easily switch between them just by changing one single value.
Also, there is no need to create M2_HOME, just follow the video.
I personally never created that M2_HOME, you can omit that part.
Just focus on MAVEN_HOME
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu2L1pg4jns

Comment: won't that installation conflict with the maven I already have on STS? Shouldn't the maven of STS and this other maven than runs on command prompt reference to the same maven installation? And what you mean by switching between them?

Comment: At the moment you do not have any maven installed that's why you are getting that error. when you are using terminal you are using your machine maven.
As for switching for an example you have 
MAVEN_HOME = /xxx/sdk/apache-maven-3.0.5
when you want to change it you just change the value
MAVEN_HOME = /xxx/sdk/apache-maven-3.3.5
and that's it.
Just follow the video and give it a try, it will work.